# Spring mongorepository save throws duplicate key exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, duplicates

I am using the java and Spring.  As a test, I query an object by id, then try to save the same object without updating anything.  I get a duplicate key exception when I do this.  According to what I've read, MongoRepository.save() should do an insert if the _id is null and an update otherwise.  Clearly, I should get an update.

A bit of code:

```
// Succeeds
Datatype sut = mongoRepository.findOne("569eac0dd4c623dc65508679");  

// Fails with duplicate key.
mongoRepository.save(sut);
```

Why?  Repeat the above with object of other classes and they work.  How can I trouble shoot this?  I don't see how to break it down and isolate the problem.

Thanks

The error:

```
27906 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] 2016-05-02 13:00:26,304 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver -

Resolving exception from handler 
[
  public gov.nist.healthcare.tools.hl7.v2.igamt.lite.web.DatatypeSaveResponse 
gov.nist.healthcare.tools.hl7.v2.igamt.lite.web.controller.DatatypeController.save(
  gov.nist.healthcare.tools.hl7.v2.igamt.lite.domain.Datatype) 
throws gov.nist.healthcare.tools.hl7.v2.igamt.lite.web.exception.DatatypeSaveException
]:
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: {
   "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" ,
   "ok" : 1 ,
   "n" : 0 , 
   "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: igl.datatype.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('569eac0dd4c623dc65508679') }" ,
   "code" : 11000};
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: {
  "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" ,
  "ok" : 1 ,
  "n" : 0 ,
  "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: igl.datatype.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('569eac0dd4c623dc65508679') }" ,
  "code" : 11000}
```

...repeats

I just made a discovery.  When saving as shown above, spring attempts an insert, this even though _id is populated.

When saving other objects ( not shown, but similar), spring performs, an update, and yes _id is again populated.

Why the difference?  The documentation says spring should update when _id is populated and insert when it is not.

Is there anything else that can be causing this?  Something in my object? perhaps my read converter?

Update:
I just met with the team.  Upon scrutiny we determined we no longer need read converters.  Problem solved by another means.

Comment: How did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 7):

In my case the issue was that I added the version for my data model class.

```
@Version
private Long version;
```

The old documents did not have one, it resolved to null, and MongoTemplate decided that this is a new document.

In this case just initialize the version with the default value (*private Long version = 0;*).

Comment: For me it was similar. I have a entity with `@Id` and `@Version`. I forgot to set the version field when updating. So I got the DuplicateKeyException. When I also set the version field for the update, it worked.

Comment: @Marvin So you need to manually increment the version yourself during the update? I thought it should be automatic?

Comment: @arxakoulini no, it 100% should be automatic

Answer (score 2):

When using read converters or write converters you can solve the issue by ensuring the object to be saved contains a non-null id field.

The SimpleMongoRepository checks if the entity is new before performing a conversion. In our instance, we had an object that did not have an id field and the write converter would add it.

Adding a populated id field to the object informs the SimpleMongoRepository to call save instead of insert.

The decision happens here. Your code may vary by Spring version. I hope this helps.

```
@Override
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null!");

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        return mongoOperations.insert(entity, entityInformation.getCollectionName());
    }

    return mongoOperations.save(entity, entityInformation.getCollectionName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the database side, You may have created Unique indexes.  please look at "https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Implement equals and hashcode methods in your Datatype entity, and make sure that mongoRepository extends CrudRepositor 
(as it is described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) to ensure that if the objects are equals save method should merge them instead of save a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience, `save()` was throwing `DuplicateKeyException` even though I just modified some fields and called save on the modified version. In my case the problem was that my `@Id` field was `long` instead of `Long`.